# AAC codec not currently supported in MXF container

Tags: ffmpeg, aac, mpeg

Having trouble encoding from `.mpg` to `.mxf` using the **aac codec**.

I've written: `ffmpeg -i [input.mpg] -c:v mpeg2video -b:v 10M -a:c aac [output.mxf]`

Everything seems fine until the error pops up.

```
[mxf @ 000002a5ade4d8c0] track 1: could not find essence container ul, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Operation not permitted
Error initializing output stream 0:1 --
[aac @ 000002a5add99880] Qavg: nan
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: MXF only supports PCM audio.

Comment: Had a feeling that was the case but I saw on Wikipedia that .mxf support virtually any codec which confused me massively. Thank you for the help!

Comment: The question remains, does FFmpeg support muxing AAC into MXF? My experiment's outcomes are negative.

Answer (score 1):

AAC in MXF is supported through [SMPTE ST 381-4](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7967899).  That document was initially published in 2017, and support for it has not yet materialized in open-source tools.

Prior to the introduction of that specification, there was an older document, [SMPTE RDD 25](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7290564), which defined how Harmonic Inc. wrote AAC into the MXF container for proxy files generated in the Spectrum product line.  That document was followed by a few companies other than Harmonic (notably Avid and Amberfin), but was not picked up by the open-source community.  IIRC, some versions of ffmpeg and/or vlc could read them (despite not officially supporting the metadata) because they would probe the essence itself.